# How to Logon in FIX Protocol?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, fix-protocol

I'm new to FIX protocol. We're using a TCP network stream to establish a connection then we read and write the FIX message to this stream. But when I send the logon message all I get is 0.

It would be helpful if someone could share a snippet of working code.

```
NetworkStream stm = openStream();
ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(data);
Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");
stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

byte[] bb = new byte[1024];
while (true)
{
    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 1024);
    if (k != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
        Console.Write(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the documentation of the library you are using. And for what have you posted the code ? Not know much C#, but this code is doing nothing related to logging in.

Comment: Thankyou..Here the data consist of logon message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are the **Initiator** side once you are sending the LOGON `(35=A)` message.

To login into a FIX server, you need

- connect to a FIX server
- send a `LOGON message (35=A)`
- receive the `LOGON message (35=A)`
- send and receive `Heartbeat messages (35=0)`

I would like to recommend you to use a FIX library to handle FIX messages. FIX Protocol has several messages (`session messages`, `application messages`, etc), some are very complex messages.
I've used http://quickfixengine.org/ for dotnet and c++ and [quickfix/j](http://www.quickfixj.org/) for java.

If you use a library, it will handle all `"session messages"` and you need to handle just the `"application messages"`, e.g. `NewOrderSingle(35=D)`, `ExecutionReport(35=8)`, etc.

To keep the FIX Connection up and running, you (or the library) need exchange several `"session messages"` to sync the IDs. The IDs (both sides) are very important receive the messages correctly.

Comment: Thankyou. i have one more doubt. I managed to  logon using quickfix. Im receiving the logon response.  But the application is not hitting the onlogon method. And also when i try to send the marketdata request, it is hitting the toApp() but not being sent out. Can you give any idea on this.?

Comment: We have several reasons to this happen. Please post here: (1) fix session log file, (2) fix session event file and (3) your IApplication code. Please remove any password or important information before send.

Comment: Hi. Solved that error, but got a new one. Im trying to send the MarketDataRequest. It is returning me that 55 tag is not specified. But im pretty sure im specifying that tag. The request and response is below.    20160622-16:40:27.464 : 8=FIX.4.49=13035=V34=249=XXXXX52=20160622-16:40:18.34356=XXXXX55=GBPUSD146=1262=App123263=1264=0265=0267=2269=010=129
20160622-16:40:27.760 : 8=FIX.4.49=13335=334=249=XXXXX52=20160622-16:40:28.04956=XXXXXX45=258=Tag not defined for this message type371=55372=V373=210=193   I have also attached the message creation code in below comment

Comment: Message msg = new Message();
            msg.Header.SetField(new MsgType("V"));
            msg.SetField(new MDReqID("PrimoApp123"));
            msg.SetField(new SubscriptionRequestType('1'));
            msg.SetField(new MarketDepth(0));
            msg.SetField(new MDUpdateType(0));
            msg.SetField(new NoMDEntryTypes(2));
            msg.SetField(new MDEntryType('0'));
            msg.SetField(new NoRelatedSym(1));
            msg.SetField(new Symbol("GBPUSD"));
            Session.SendToTarget(msg, FeederApp.mysession);

Comment: Hi, you received a 35=3 (REJECT) message. There are several REJECTION MESSAGES but this specific one is related to INVALID PROTOCOL MESSAGES.

Comment: The problem is: according to the FIX.4.4, the Market Data Request message must inform the REPEATING GROUP named NoRelatedSym. You are setting the SYMBOL at msg variable instead of set SYMBOL at the NoRelatedSym group.     quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym group = new quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym(1); group.setSymbol("GBPUSD"); msg.addGroup(group); Got it?

Comment: FIX Protocol Central Message => http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/     MarketDataRequest FIX44 message => www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.4/body_505786.html

Comment: I'd recommend you if you have any other question, we can mark this question as answered and open a new one. I believe it would be better to the community and for google search. @VivekJeevaKumar

Comment: Thanks. as per your suggestion i have raised a new question. If possible look into that and help me pls.